# Unity Cloud Build: post export method

Tags: c#, ios, .net, unity-game-engine

Problem:

I can't seem to figure out the right signature for Unity cloud build's post export method. According to the documentation:

> The fully-qualified name of a public static method you want us to call
>   after we finish the Unity build process (but before Xcode). For
>   example: ClassName.CoolMethod or NameSpace.ClassName.CoolMethod. No
>   trailing parenthesis, and it can't have the same name as your
>   Pre-Export method! This method must accept a string parameter, which
>   will receive the path to the exported Unity player (or Xcode project
>   in the case of iOS).

Here is my code:

```
 public static void OnPostprocessDevBuildIOS(string ExportPath)
    {
        var projPath = ExportPath + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

        var proj = new PBXProject();
        var nativeTarget =
            proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());
        var testTarget =
            proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTestTargetName());
        string[] buildTargets = {nativeTarget, testTarget};

        proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));
        proj.SetBuildProperty(buildTargets, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");
        File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.WriteToString());
    }
```

and here is the error:

[image]

I've tried multiple test method signatures and can't seem to get anything to work. I've even tried just a method that logs out the path.

Additional Information:

- Unity Version: 5.3.1f
- Unity Cloud Build: 5.3.1f
- Target: iOS 8.0+

Also, my cloud build settings script is located in the editor folder as required.

[image]

Ok so I got the the bitCode disabling post process to work with the following code, but only when I build manually. When I build from cloud build, with no error the app freezes at the splash screen. When I build from my local machine, the app runs just fine.

```
[PostProcessBuild]
public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
{
    if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
    {
        string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
        PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
        proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));

        string nativeTarget = proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());
        string testTarget = proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTestTargetName());
        string[] buildTargets = new string[]{nativeTarget, testTarget};

        proj.SetBuildProperty(buildTargets, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");
        File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.WriteToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue "splash screen stuck" right after launch....
I solved this issue. Please use the below code.
Tested in Unity 5.4.1p2 and Xcode 7.3.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
#if UNITY_IOS
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
#endif

public class Postprocessor : AssetPostprocessor
{   
#if UNITY_IOS
    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

            PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
            proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));

            string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

            proj.SetBuildProperty(target, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "false");

            File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.WriteToString());



            // Add url schema to plist file
            string plistPath = path + "/Info.plist";
            PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
            plist.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(plistPath));

            // Get root
            PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;
            rootDict.SetBoolean("UIRequiresFullScreen",true);
            plist.WriteToFile(plistPath);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In fact OnPostprocessBuild is always called, so you don't have to put anything in post export method field, which is designed for more specific methods.

Comment: without OnPostProcessBuild, how can I disable BITCODE ?